# How to compile Android 4.1/4.2 Camera+Gallery App together

Tags: android, camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean

The Android Camera and Gallery has been merged in Android 4.1 and above.

Now, I want to play around with the Android 4.2 Camera app, and try to port it on my older devices.

How do I compile https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/ and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/

As far as the sources etc are concerned, both of these should be compiled together.However, the Camera source doesn't have a manifest, which makes it impossible to port on Eclipse.

So, I need help with:

1.How to import both of these projects?

2.How to join them together as one single apk (I tried merging the res and src folders, but still a lot of compiling errors).

3.The Camera source, while calling up popup menus, make reference to R.styleable references to populate the list, instead of normal arrays, which I'm unable to fix. The problem becomes manifold when I set the build target to ICS, because the R.styleable references refuse to cooperate. Deleting them brings up empty popup menus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: styleabale resources are defined in Camera `res/values/attrs.xml`, and there should be no problem to use them for any target platform. What exactly do you mean by _refuse to cooperate_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple source folders in a Java project (Android project is a subtype of Java project in this sense).

Comment: But how do I import the Camera source in the first place? It doesn't have a manifest. Gallery has a manifest, but I can't import it because it needs the Camera.

Comment: I can easily "Import existing Android code Into Workspace" with Gallery. Then, I can add source folder to Camera code: Properties/Java Build Path/Link Source. But these projects were depend on other platform libraries, IMHO. You are not supposed to build them in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. Now I was able to link source.